# Setting the high resolution image to UIimageView create memory issue

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-management, uiimageview

I have app that have two screen. i am sending `UIImage` object from first screen to second and set this image to `UIImageview` in second screen.

But when i tried to set image in `UIImageview` my memory spike goes to 116 up. My image resolution is above **2040*2040**

Here is my code

*.h file*

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *aimageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIImage *sourceImage;
```

*.m file*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    aimageView.image = sourceImage;
    [aimageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    sourceImage = nil;
}
```

Comment: change your image resolution.

Answer (score 1):

When an image is uncompressed in memory it can take up a lot of memory.

If you are developing for iPhone, where the max screen resolution is 640x1136 then why do you need to load a 2040x2040 image at once?

If you need to efficiently handle large images in your app, it might be worth looking at using a `CATiledLayer`. This would allow you to split large images down into smaller image tiles and then only load the tiles the user wants to see on the screen.

Apple have a sample project that you can find [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html).